# How do I check if a string with a user given input is equal to a certain letter/ word in Python

Tags: python, string, while-loop, comparison, equality

This isn't working and I don't know why. Help needed!

I have defined a string:

```
userin = "h"
```

I ask the user for an input:

```
userin = raw_input()
```

I have a while loop that runs if the string is not equal to a certain letter and an if (within the while) that checks if the string is equal to a certain letter:

```
while (userin!="c" or low == high):
userin = raw_input()
if userin is "c"
    break
```

Comment: use `==` instead of `is`

Comment: Sorry, we didn't get your requirement and issue , what is the issue?

Comment: why do you need the `if userin is "c"` condition? it's already been taken care of in the `while` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indent your code correctly

```
while (userin!="c" or low == high):
    userin = raw_input()
```

Comment: In general, `==` should be used instead of `is` unless you specifically need `is`.